Failure to Install Axis2 1.8.2 Eclipse Plugins
I've downloaded the Apache Axis2 1.8.2 Eclipse plugins from https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html:
axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.8.2-dist.zip
axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.8.2-dist.zip
After unpacking, I noticed that both zip files contain identically named JAR files in their plugins directory, named ${bundle-symbolic-name}_${bundle-version}.jar. I then copied these JAR files into the Eclipse dropins directory, but the plugins did not install. I'm using the Eclipse 2022-06 version.
Could there be something wrong with the files I downloaded, or is there another issue at play?
Thank you.

Obviously something seems to have gone wrong, causing the unresolved JAR name. In the ZIP archive axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.8.2-dist.zip ${bundle-symbolic-name}_${bundle-version}.jar should be named org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.8.2.jar and in axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.8.2-dist.zip the plugin should be named org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.8.2.jar. Please report this to the Apache  Axis2/Java project.

In the dropins folder, adding these two plugins as axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.8.2-dist/plugins/${bundle-symbolic-name}_${bundle-version}.jar and axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.8.2-dist/plugins/${bundle-symbolic-name}_${bundle-version}.jar might also work. By the way, Eclipse 2022-06 is almost two years and 7 releases behind. Please upgrade.

Hello @howlger ,I just attempted to install the plugins using the Eclipse 2024-06 version, but unfortunately, I couldn't get them to install.

Is there anything in the error log? If yes, please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-6042 has been reported.
